How to calculate the double sine function via Sage or Pari/GP to high precision?
From a paper of Ruijsenaars, we can extract the following integral representation for the logarithm of the double sine function:
$$\log(S_2(w,z)) = \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{e^{-y(1+w-z)}-e^{-yz}}{(1-e^{-y})(1-e^{-wy})} - \frac{1}{y}(\frac{2z}{w}-\frac {1}{w} -1 ) \right)  \frac{dy}{y} $$
In Sage, it is straightforward to implement this function using the procedure "numerical_integral". It works just fine and produces results in perfect alignment with the known values of the double sine function. (E.g., we have $S_2(w,1) = \sqrt{w}$).
My problem is, that I don't know how to increase the number of digits I can get using "numerical_integral". I only get around 16 digits in the decimal expansion, but for my applications I need at least 32.
Question 1: How to increase the number of digits in Sage for the output of the procedure "numerical_integral"?
In other words, how can I increase the precision of the procedure "numerical_integral"?
Here is my code:
numerical_integral(( (e^(-(1+w-z)*y)-e^(-z*y))/((1-e^(-y))*(1-e^(-w*y))) -1/y*(2*z/w-1/w-1) )/y,0,+Infinity,max_points=200)

I tried to use Gp/Pari, which automatically gives a larger number of digits, using the procedure "intnum". If I do the straightforward implementation of the same code which runs nicely on Sage, I don't get any output. (The procedure uses enormous amount of memory, but doesn't produce any output.
Question 2: How do I compute the double sine function in Gp/Pari?
Here is the gp Code (used in Sage):
gp("s2(y,w,z) = ( (exp(-(1+w-z)*y)-exp(-z*y))/((1-exp(-y))*(1-exp(-w*y))) -1/y*(2*z/w-1/w-1) )/y  ")
gp("intnum(y = [0,2],+oo, s2(y,w,z))")

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

This is not a math question, it is a Sage question, and Gp/Pari question,

pari/gp's intnum attempts to compute the integral to the current precision (set by default(realprecision,n) or just \p ), which is 38 by default. I don't know how much precision it guarantees for reasonable functions.

Instead of downvoting, you could also point me to the right place then...

Thanks a lot for your helpful comment! @Noam D. Elkies

Notwithstanding the downvotes (which I agree with, this should properly be asked on a Pari/GP or Sage forum), here are some answers.

Clearly the numerical integration of Sage is much better than Pari.
However, Sage is also multiprecision, I am surprised that it is limited to 16D
unless they use a black box implementation working in double precision.
To do it in Pari do as follows:
There are two singularities: at 0 and at $\infty$. At $\infty$ the problem is that
the behavior of the exponential part is completely different from the other,
and this confuses Pari. The solution is to split into 2 functions: $s21(y,w,z)$
the exponential part, and $s22(y,w,z)$ the rational function part. Then
intnum(y=1,[oo,1],s21(y,w,z)) should work, and of course
intnum(y=1,oo,s22(y,w,z)) also but this is trivial.

At 0 the singularity is only apparent, so putting y=[0,2] as endpoint does not
solve the problem. The solution is to do the expansion around 0 and tell
Pari to use the expansion close to 0. For instance, to compute for w=2 and z=1
you would write $s2(y,2,1)$ which will give you $1/12-7/720*y^2+\cdots$. Then
the integral from 0 to 1 is computed by
intnum(y=0,1,if(abs(y)<10^(-20),1/12,s2(y,2,1)))
where 20 is half the desired accuracy (by defaut 38). Hope this helps.
In any case, the double sine function is more and more used, a proper implementation is certainly desirable.

Thank you very much for your very helpful answer!

I wasn't able to locate a Pari/GP forum before I asked the question. Seeing all the negative reactions I should definitely have tried a Sage forum first... That being said, a proper implementation of the double sine function (and generalizations) is certainly very desirable and of interest for many mathematicians! So maybe not the worst place to bring the problem to the attention of mathematicians...

Only a remark: sage has tools other than gp/pari. As in python you can always use`
from mpmath import *
mp.dps = 100 # digits of precision`
and then you get f.i.
sin(1.2)
mpf('0.9320390859672263496701344354948259954150705882087307353665978944502423415767920542157417224381184959611')
This gives floating point math with arbitrary presicion (of course you are loosing speed). Maybe mpmath is implemented in your version of sage.

Thanks a lot, this has been extremely helpful! Integration in mpmath is done via the procedure "quad", which produces remarkably precise results! :)
